# Error 'PDone' object has no attribute 'windowing' dataflow WriteToPubSub

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a beam pipeline which reads records from two Postgres CloudSQL DBs, does some data transformations and pushes the data to Google PubSub via `WriteToPubSub` module. \

I am able to run this pipeline locally as DirectRunner, where the connection to CloudSQL and publish to PubSub both work fine.

But when I include `runner='DataflowRunner'` as a pipeline option, the pipeline fails with the error,
'PDone' object has no attribute 'windowing'.

This error happens in `get_windowing` function inside the `ptransform.py` module in beam.

I am not sure what difference running the code in Dataflow runner could introduce.

is this because of some permission issue that Dataflow is not able to talk to PubSub or CloudSQL or do I need to specify some specific options for windowing even when writing to PubSub?

The following snippet shows the major pipeline flow.

```
# Invoker code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up your PostgreSQL connection parameters
    db_config = {
        'host': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'port': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
        'database': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'user': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'password': os.getenv('DB_PASS')
    }
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    print(args)
    publish_topic = os.getenv('PUBLISH_TOPIC')

    # Set up Apache Beam pipeline options
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        beam_args,
        runner='DataflowRunner',
        project='<gcp-project-id>',
        job_name='dispatch-demo-1',
        temp_location='<bucket path>',
        region='europe-west1')

    dispatch_args = pipeline_options.view_as(DispatchOptions)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        # Create a dummy input element
        dummy_input = pipeline | beam.Create(['dummy'])

        client_operations_query = f"SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE attr1=abc"
        get_retailer_categories_query = 'SELECT * FROM table1'

        co_rows = dummy_input | 'Get table1 rows' >> ReadDB(
            client_operations_query, **db_config) | 'CO list to map' >> beam.Map(list_to_dict, 'internal_category_id')

        co_rows | "co_rows " >> beam.Map(print)

        retailer_cat_rows = dummy_input | 'Get table2 rows' >> ReadDB(
            get_retailer_categories_query, **db_config) | 'Table2 list to map' >> beam.Map(list_to_dict, 'internal_category_id')

        retailer_cat_rows | "retailer_cat_rows" >> beam.Map(print)

        denormalised_co_rows = (({
            'co_rows': co_rows, 'retailer_cat_rows': retailer_cat_rows
        })
            | 'group by cat_ids' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
            | 'Join by cat_id' >> beam.ParDo(MergeTransform()))

        groupedRows = denormalised_co_rows | beam.GroupBy(get_hash) | 'ExtractClientIds' >> beam.Map(lambda element: (element[0], [obj['client_id'] for obj in element[1]], element[1])) | "Convert to string" >> beam.Map(
            encode_as_task) | "Write to Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=publish_topic) | "pubsub out print" >> beam.Map(print)
```

Comment: I think after `beam.Map(print)` your `PCollection`s are empty. Remove the two print steps and try again.

Comment: Removed that. still issue exists.

Comment: did you also remove this print from `"Write to Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=publish_topic) | "pubsub out print" >> beam.Map(print)? If you need to log elements for testing, you could always use `https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.util.html#apache_beam.transforms.util.LogElements` as the part of your pipeline, which returns the input PCollection as the output but still prints all elements.
`

Comment: yes. i removed those. those were not causing any issues @XQHu. Found the issue. posted that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the permission of Dataflow to access the CloudSQL instance and permission to publish topics to pubsub.

Adding the following roles (`"roles/cloudsql.client"`) and (`roles/pubsub.publisher`) to google dataflow service account - `service-<project-number>@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
solved the issue.

Comment: Did you see any permission errors from the Dataflow worker logs?

Comment: no. @XQHu. that was the weird part.

Comment: Yeah it's working with pubsub.publisher